# 404 error when try to import files in html

Tags: javascript, python, html, pycharm

I have a project in pycharm which use app.py to call the page1 and page2_test html file. My project structure is like this:
[Project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OW0HR.png)
All the csv and jpg files are in the data folder.

My app.py file is like this:

```
from flask import Flask, request, render_template, redirect, url_for, session, jsonify
from datetime import datetime
import logging
from portfolio import portfolio

#app = Flask(__name__)
app = Flask(__name__, static_url_path='/data')
app.secret_key = 'your_secret_key'  # Replace 'your_secret_key' with a real secret key

@app.route('/')
def home():
    return render_template('page1.html')

@app.route('/trading', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def trading_page():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        crypto = request.form.get('crypto')
        start_date = request.form.get('start-date')
        session['trading_data'] = {'crypto': crypto, 'start_date': start_date}
        logging.info(f"Trading page accessed with crypto: {crypto}, start date: {start_date}")
        print(f"Trading page accessed with crypto: {crypto}, start date: {start_date}")
        #global portfolio =
    return render_template('page2_test.html', title='Trading Page', data=session.get('trading_data', {}))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True, port=5002)
```

For example, I want to import the a jpg file as my background. In the html, I have:

```
background-image: url('{{ url_for('static', filename='Background1.jpg') }}');
```

However, when I get to page2_test with the url http://127.0.0.1:5002/trading. The Background1.jpg cannot be found. I get the error:[404 error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VSKtW.png)

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. The file that stores the data should be called static. I called it data. That caused the problem.